# Rails API access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am creating an API using rails. When a user logs in (passes in username/password), rather than setting a cookie, I want to respond with a 'token' that I want to send the client. This token probably has an expiration date on it and the user_id i store internally which links the token with the user, etc. Is there a tutorial or gem I can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Railscasts.com has a wonderful [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast) dedicated to the same issue, worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to send a token (not a gem that takes care of the whole process), you can use `render inline: "token"` (or a json equivalent)